# Plugins not showing on dashboard?

Tags: plugins, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I've seen other people post the same question but I think my scenario is a bit different.

My plugins WERE working fine UNTIL I created 2 additional sites and added an extension plugin.

So basically my website structure looked like this:

/public_html/ <-- main site

/public_html/test/ <-- second site

/public_html/test2/ <-- third site

I forgot exactly when the problem started occurring, but there was a moment when I was installing a new plugin (it was  NextGen gallery extension) on my main site in the same manner that I install all of my other plugins (which were all working fine), then out of nowhere, I get this error saying that my nextgen gallery file (not the extension) was missing a valid header or something.  Next thing I knew, all of my plugins EXCEPT the gallery extension plugin disappeared.  They are still in the server but not showing up in the dashboard.  It's as though the extension plugin screwed something up.

Any ideas?  Kinda weird.  I could try deactivating the extension plugin....haven't done it yet but wondered if anybody else had ideas.  How does one plugin cause a mess to other plugins that were working fine?

Comment: If you can, you might want to set WP_DEBUG to true on your sites to see if there is an obvious problem cropping up. If you cannot, you might set WP_DEBUG to true, and WP_DEBUG_LOG to true as well (in your wp_config.php file) to have wordpress log any problems to a log file in your wp-content directory. Last I checked NextGen was poorly written and could very well be the problem. Just move it out of your plugins directory ... and if things return to normal you can experiment further.

Comment: set WP_DEBUG to true, created WP_DEBUG_LOG as a new definition and set it to true.  Renamed the plugins directory, then recreated it and put a few of the plugins that were working in it (the nextgen plugins were in the renamed folder).  So there was a "plugin_backup" and a "plugins" directory.  Refreshed the frond end of the site and backend.  Plugins still not appearing and there is an error on the front of the site: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/funnykit/public_html/wp-content/themes/pinstrap/includes/strap-extras.php on line 71.

Comment: There's a bunch of non-object errors in the same file on different lines, but I'm not convinced that the theme has any connection to the plugins not working (unless someone tells me otherwise).  so....I'm still baffled.  Does having additional sites cause issues?  I have one site under public_html and two other sites in two other folders. public_html/test and public_html/test2.  I still need one of those test sites so I can bring the other test site down but need some confirmation on this...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the site I was developing was utilizing this plugin to show gallery on the homepage. The first few days the site was working well but when I launched a persistent white screen of death error developed.

I used the FTP access to rename the plugin file to something like(old_plugins) in this directory wp-content/old_plugins. I refreshed the site and realized the site as back and therefore concluded its a plugin problem.

I started sorting them one by one...when I came to Next Gen when I activated it the white screen of death error was back.

I simply deleted it and the error was gone. When I researched about the bugs of NEXT GEN I realized that even the plugin author acknowledges they released the latest version (2.0.0) with several bugs. http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/open-letter-to-the-nextgen-community-from-erick-danzer/

The root problem is a conflict with other caching plugins, esp nextgen plugin from version 2.0.0

I hope that helps.

Comment: I have no idea what the error was.  I literally renamed the entire plugins folder into a different name, then created a new empty plugins folder, downloaded a fresh copy of the latest version of Wordpress, put Akismet (one of the plugins that comes with Wordpress) into the new empty plugins folder, then refreshed the plugins page in the dashboard.  No plugins showed.  So I said screw it....I backed all my files up, then deleted all of the files except for my gallery pictures (which were in a separate non-plugins folder inside wp-content), then uploaded a fresh copy of Wordpress.

Comment: Then I put back my old wp-config and wp-settings file, then all of my plugins and themes.  Everything returned back to normal.  So I'm not sure what happened.  Seems like there might have been a corrupted file somewhere in wp-admin or wp-includes or somewhere in the root directory.  But now apparently after activated the NextGen extension plugin, it is having a "connection lost" error whenever I update a page.  Might need to find an alternative plugin.